# Distributions whose domain are themshelves a distribution

Tags: nonparametric, dirichlet-process

[Dirichlet process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_process), [Pitman Yor processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitman%E2%80%93Yor_process) and their variants are special types of distributions whose domain are themshelves a distribution. Is there a name to refer to these distributions in general?  What other distributions have the same property?